# ¿Cómo puedo analizar solo un tipo de archivo o varios en sonarqube?

Tags: sonar, sonarqube

Estoy intentando analizar solamente archivos .java y .js omitiendo el análisis de todos los demás archivos , ya que contiene archivos como .pdf o csv etc.. que causan problemas de compilación, pero son al rededor de 50 extensiones de archivos que omitir por lo feo del proyecto.

Se que lo mejor seria depurarlo, pero por motivos de tiempos ¿alguno sabe como pudo analizar solo los .java y .js omitiendo todo lo demás?

y no quiero colocar una por una de las extensiones.

```
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*.pdf,**/*.csv,**/*.jpg, etc...
```

intentos:

```
-Dsonar.inclusions=**/*.java -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.java.source=1.6 -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec -Dsonar.scm.disabled=true -X

-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*?.java -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.java.source=1.6 -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec -Dsonar.scm.disabled=true -X
```

Saben alguna manera?

Comment: Esa definición de file types a analizar la das por cada lenguaje que analizas en Sonarqube, `Project settings > General settings > Language`. Eso normalmente evita que revise los .pepe que creo a veces. De resto, las exclusiones [son tal cual](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) las indicas